# Why did my question suddenly become popular?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question in 2018:

[What was the early understanding of static electricity shocks?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/48677/28579)

Didn't have much attention, and then it was answered a year later in Nov 2019.

Then, for some reason, in the past month or so it started getting so many views I was awarded a gold badge for it. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely somebody with a large audience linked it, but I don't know how we'd check to find out who.

Comment: My guess would be that [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/history/comments/ez2atb/how_did_a_preelectric_world_interpret_static/) is just that much bigger than us?

Comment: On second thought, 'current' events that direct a g-search for 'history static shock' to https://twitter.com/hashtag/StaticShock, the above and here? (Are all good backlink checkers now pay-ware?)